# Auto-Remove element after being created (Javascript/Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've been developing a few functions on JavaScript to display messages on the screen. The function I'm about is this:

- **showMsg()**: Creates an element and appends it into another element.

What I want to do is, given that the function is activated via **click**, append a timer to *this* very element and remove it after 3 seconds.

I've tried many ways to accomplish it with setTimeouts and removing the elements within container with listeners like *bind.('DOMSubtreeModified')* on the container where **showMsg()** element is being appended to.

**I need to give the created element a X timer and remove the element after that X timer ends. Like a sticky bomb, attached to the very element**

Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to have it set to the object in specific? If you want the item to get destroyed after a set time you can simply do this by having saving the object's reference to a variable then having it get destroyed with `.remove()` inside a `setTimeout`.

The instance of the setTimeout won't be destroyed so it will act just like having it connected to the object in most use cases.

For example: Here is what I have written that works for what I think you are going for here.

```js
function spawnTemp() {
  var deleteMe = $("<div style='height: 100px; width: 100px; background: lime;'>My Message</div>").appendTo("#eleContainer");
  setTimeout(function() {
    deleteMe.remove();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="spawnElement" onclick="spawnTemp();">Spawn Temporary</button>
  <div id="eleContainer">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Note: in this code I use the `appendTo()` method to get the instance of the appended object, this allows me to then delete that instance through its reference I stored in the variable `deleteMe`.

If you were using `append()` then the stored variable would have been referencing the container that is the parent of the appended object.

---

If you absolutely need the element to have the timer attached to it, then you can use the more complex,

```
$("new html").appendTo('container').delay(2000).queue(function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

Though, it is hard to think of why you might use this over the alternative `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, specially Liam for giving me the right approach I needed.

It finally worked out, but in a bit different way.

Calling the function **showMsg** and storing it into a variable wouldn't allow me to make the timer work, It will create the element and so but it won't remove it.

What I finally did was to create a variable and paste the "**result**" of the function showMsg(), and then the timer would work. It ended up like this:

****THE ANSWER BY THE MOMENT****

```
var elem = $("<div>You must be logged first my friend</div>").appendTo('.notification-bar');
    setTimeout( function() {
        $(elem).remove();
    }, 3000);
```

And all works well by now.

****THE PROBLEM I HAD, EXPLAINED****

This is what I was supossed to do:

Functions I got:

**createElement**: Creates an element with the given attr, data and place

```
function createElement(element, attributes, position, text) {
var object = $(document.createElement(element)); // Element creation
$.each(attributes, function(key, value) { // Array of attributes
    object.attr(key, value); // Attr: Value
});
$(object).appendTo(position); // Place
$(object).append(text); // Text
```

}

**showMsg()**: Uses *createElement* to create and place a div

```
function showMsg() {
createElement('div', null, '.notification-bar', "You must be logged first my friend");
```

}

**onclick trigger**: Called on body load. * *This was supossed to work* *

```
$('.reply-button').click(function(event) {
    var elem = notifyUser('You must be logged first my friend');
    setTimeout( function() {
        $(elem).remove();
    }, 3000);

});
```

If anyone has a clue of how to perform the previous problematic, please let me now

Thank you in advance ;)